# Azure DevOps Artifact Feed restoring deleted package

Tags: npm, azure-devops

We have an issue where we are trying to run an `npm install` in a DevOps build pipeline but one of the packages is no longer in our private feed. Under the *Upstream Versions* tab it is listed as `Deleted from feed`, although none of us did delete it. The `Save to feed` button is grayed out so cannot seem to restore it. I've checked the recycle bin and the package isn't in there either. Having read around online, it would seem that once a specific version of a package is deleted, it is impossible to restore. Is this correct? If so is there a workaround?

I would just adjust our package.json file to use a newer minor version but the npm package isn't listed in there and therefore must be referenced by another package somewhere.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.